# Jekyll forloop.last --> before last?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, for-loop, jekyll, liquid

I made a dummy "related posts" in *Jekyll 3.2.1* with the following solution:

```
    {% for post in site.posts limit: 4 %}
    {% if page.author == post.author and page.title != post.title %}
    <div class="post-stream-item">
    <a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}" title="{{ post.title  }}"><div class="post-stream-content">
        <img src="{{ post.thumbnail }}" width="80" height="auto" /><span class="post-stream-item-meta"><h3>{{ post.title }}</h3><p>{{ post.author }} on {{ post.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }} •     {% assign words = post.content | number_of_words %}
        {% if words <= 160 %}
        1 min
        {% else %}
        {{ words | plus: 159 | divided_by:160 }} mins
        {% endif %} read</p></span></div></a></div>{% if forloop.last == false %}<hr>{% endif %}

        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

1. The for loop iterates through the posts list in the site and gives
   it a limit
2. If the author of the current post is the same as the author of the
   iterated post, but the title is not the same, then it fills out the
   jinja bindings.

**The problem is with the** `{% if forloop.last == false %}<hr>{% endif %}` **part, cause if there is more iterable (post) in the forloop, it will display the** `<hr>` **tag, even if it's the last element shown to the user**.

Is there any attribute to refer to the penultimate element of the list or any better solution to this?

Comment: Did you consider testing the forloop.index against the forloop length minus one?

Comment: That could be a solution there, @JoostS , I will try to play with them!

Comment: @JoostS That won't really work, since you don't know ahead of time which index of the loop will be the last iteration where the `if` statement is executed.

Comment: David's answer below made me realize your code has a logic error: notice that you're limiting the posts to 4, and then looping through them. What if none of the posts you want to find are in the first 4 posts of the overall site?

Comment: @KevinWorkman you're right and you guys helped me a lot, it just taught me to think more about my situation and ask more general questions rather than situation-based questions. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @hzoltan, would you be able to update your question with the solution that worked?  I am trying to implement 2 loops, but can't quite get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Print a certain number of posts with no print condition

Solution : use loop `limit`

```
{% for post in site.posts limit: 4 %}
    ... output code here
{% endfor %}
```

You will print exactly 4 posts and forloop.last always works.

#### Print a certain number of posts with a print condition in the loop

Solution : use `where` filter, a `counter` and `break`

Now that you include a conditional printing :

- you don't know which and how many posts will be printed.
- if you don't print last post, you have an HR at the end of your list.

If you want to know how many posts you can print, you can use `{% assign authorsPosts = site.posts | where: "author", page.author %}` and `authorsPosts.size`.

This code will do it nicely, even if available posts number is less than your limit.

```
{% comment %} +++++ Max number of posts to print +++++ {% endcomment %}
{% assign limit = 4 %}

{% comment %} +++++ Select authors posts +++++{% endcomment %}
{% assign authorsPosts = site.posts | where: "author", page.author %}

{% comment %} +++++ If author's Posts number is less than limit, we change the limit +++++ {% endcomment %}
{% if limit >= authorsPosts.size %}
  {% comment %} +++++ Number of "listable" posts is author's posts number less 1 (the one actually printed) +++++ {% endcomment %}
  {% assign limit = authorsPosts.size | minus: 1 %}
{% endif %}

{% assign postsCounter = 0 %}
{% for post in authorsPosts %}
  {% if page.author == post.author and page.title != post.title %}

    {% assign postsCounter = postsCounter | plus: 1 %}

    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>

    {% comment %} +++++ Prints hr only if we are not printing the last post +++++ {% endcomment %}
    {% if postsCounter < limit %}<hr>{% endif %}

    {% comment %} +++++ Exit for loop if we reached the limit +++++ {% endcomment %}
    {% if postsCounter == limit %}{% break %}{% endif %}

  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking. The OP is asking specifically about the last `<hr>` element. They want to print the `<hr>` elements between posts. In other words, they're asking how to **not** print the `<hr>` element after the **last** post they find. This might be a separate problem the OP will face with their code, but it isn't what they're asking about... yet.

Comment: @KevinWorkman My code had a problem if author has less posts than limit. I've corrected my code. It now does exactly what the OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't going to be a simple out-of-the-box one-line solution for this. Think about it this way: you're essentially asking for a feature that looks ahead in time and figures out whether this is the last time the `if` statement will evaluate to `true`. Jekyll is great, but it can't predict the future!

You could do this yourself by using two loops: one that loops through and counts how many `<hr>` elements you should show. Then another that actually prints stuff out, checking against the count you came up with to decide whether to print the `<hr>` element.

Or you could just use CSS to hide the last `<hr>` element. Google is your friend here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kevin, I just exploring Jekyll's possibilities right now and using it for about a few weeks ago. It seems like you're right, thank you for your help.

Comment: @hzoltan No problem. I actually just started learning about Jekyll myself not too long ago!